# How to map array based on index position

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have one local date Array Called mainDateArray, i used to call APi Calls to some response, From the resonse i get two Arrays Called "Dates" and "RecordCount". This Dates and record Count have same length and recordCount Array Contains values respective to the "Dates" from the server.

later i need to Draw graph based on this two "mainDateArray" and "recordCount" 
if dates Array values does not match with mainDateArray i need to append or push 0 to the "recordsCount" Array

To be more clear

```
mainDateArray = ["05-May-19","06-May-19","07-May-19","08-May-19","09-May-19","10-May-19","11-May-19"];
dates = ["06-May-19","08-May-19","10-May-19"]; // response date
recordsCount = [20,30,10];  // data for the above dates Array from response
```

My expected output

```
op = [0,20,0,30,0,10,0];
example:=> ["05-May-19"=0,"06-May-19"=20,"07-May-19"=0,"08-May-19"=30,"09-May-19"=0,"10-May-19"=10,"11-May-19"=10]
```

i.e when my response date not includes the maindateArray i need to append 0 in recordCount data any hepls would be helpful for me

Comment: What are 20, 30 and 10 in your `recordsCount`? Why those values?

Comment: You implied you have mainDateArray locally and get "dates" and "recordcount" arrays from the server, then you went and called your mainDateArray the response from the server in your code (so mainDateArray and response are the same thing), and later you appear to again imply that "mainDateArray" and [response] "dates" are different things. Please can you have another read over your post and fill it out a bit. Right now it's very confusing and I personally cannot work out what you're asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`Array​​.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array​​.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```js
var mainDateArray = ["05-May-19", "06-May-19", "07-May-19", "08-May-19", "09-May-19", "10-May-19", "11-May-19"]
var dates = ["06-May-19", "08-May-19", "10-May-19"]
var recordsCount = [20, 30, 10]

var result = mainDateArray.map((v, i) => recordsCount[dates.indexOf(v)] || 0)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) of the `date` -> `recordsCount` and then [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over `mainDateArray` array, checking if the date exists in the map or not.

```js
const mainDateArray = [
  "05-May-19",
  "06-May-19",
  "07-May-19",
  "08-May-19",
  "09-May-19",
  "10-May-19",
  "11-May-19"
];
const dates = ["06-May-19", "08-May-19", "10-May-19"]; // response date
const recordsCount = [20, 30, 10]; // data for the above dates Array from response

const datesMap = new Map(dates.map((date, idx) => [date, recordsCount[idx]]));

const op = mainDateArray.map(date =>
  datesMap.has(date) ? datesMap.get(date) : 0
);

console.log(op);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way IMO is to use an object to keep track of the counts.

```
// create object for key (i.e. date) based lookup
var counts = {};
for(var i in mainDateArray){
    var date = mainDateArray[i];
    counts[date] = 0;
}

// update counts
for(var i in dates){
    var date = dates[i];
    counts[date] += recordsCount[i];
}

// output
var op = [];
for(var i in mainDateArray){
    var date = mainDateArray[i];
    op.push(counts[date]);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Since you've posted code that doesn't depend on anything external, you could create a stack snippet (use the `<>` icon when editing) and create an executable snippet. This will help to see what your code outputs, without having to run it elsewhere. Also, it increases the chances of your answer being accepted/upvoted. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
mainDateArray = [
  "05-May-19",
  "06-May-19",
  "07-May-19",
  "08-May-19",
  "09-May-19",
  "10-May-19",
  "11-May-19"
];
dates = ["06-May-19", "08-May-19", "10-May-19"]; // response date
recordsCount = [20, 30, 10];
op = [];
for (let i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < mainDateArray.length; j++) {
    if (dates[i] === mainDateArray[j]) {
      op[j] = recordsCount[i];
    } else {
      if (!op[j]) op[j] = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Please try this will work ..

  <script 
      src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"> 
     </script>
     <script>
     var mainDateArray = ["05-May-19","06-May-19","07-May-19","08-May-19","09-May- 
     19","10-May-19","11-May-19"];
     var output       = [];     
     var dates = ["06-May-19","08-May-19","10-May-19"]; // response date

    for(var i=0; i<mainDateArray.length; i++)
    {
     if($.inArray(mainDateArray[i],dates)!=-1)
    {
        output.push(mainDateArray[i]);
    }
    else
     {
        output.push("0");
     }
   }    
   alert(output.toString());
   </script>
```

output = [0,06-May-19,0,08-May-19,0,10-May-19,0]